# Gmap3 adding a simple context menu

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

So I'm trying to add a pretty simple context menu like the example given at:

http://gmap3.net/examples/context-menu.html

However, this example is pretty complex and not a great starting point to learn from.

I simply want to create a context menu that has 2 or 3 outbound links (that include the latlng on right click). Can anyone give me a simpler example to work from?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found something yet, I am also looking for a GM V3 context menu library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168394/google-map-v3-context-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, you will need to change the following code:

```
 // MENU : ITEM 1
  menu.add('Direction to here', 'itemB', 
    function(){
      menu.close();
      addMarker(false);
    });

etc.
```

Now, to add your own contect menu items, try something like this

```
  menu.add('OutboundLink1', 'CSS_class_for_this_link', 
    function(){
        var lat=$map.gmap3('getLatlng').lat();
        var lon=$map.gmap3('getLatlng').lon();
        window.open('someurl?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon, 'window name', 'window settings');
        menu.close();
    });

etc.
```

Note that you will have to provide your own CSS styling for the context menu.